# Cannot load such file -- /xsd threw by controller when adding a library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, xsd

I'm trying to load a library from a Controller and it is throwing me this error

`cannot load such file -- /xsd`

It is, in fact, being loaded in the first line of the library file

```
require 'xsd/qname'

# {http://www.f2b.com.br/soap/wsbillingaction.xsd}F2bAcaoCobranca
#   mensagem - F2bAcaoCobranca::Mensagem
#   cliente - F2bAcaoCobranca::Cliente
#   acao_cobranca - F2bAcaoCobranca::Acao_cobranca
class F2bAcaoCobranca
  #...
end
```

The library's file is in the following directory:

```
lib
--f2b
  --acao_cobranca
    --wsbillingaction.rb
```

And my controller's action has the following lines of code

```
def index
   require 'f2b/acao_cobranca/wsbillingaction.rb'
end
```

What is giving me this error? Is it some old stuff from previous versions of Ruby/Rails? How can I fix it?

Comment: is `lib` folder in your loadpath? (Also, you have to ommit the .rb extension.)

Comment: well I though it was by default. can you tell me how to do it? remember, `wsbillingaction` is being imported, the class 'xsd/qname` is the one giving me a headache

Answer (score 1):

`wsbillingaction` depend on another lib (`xsd/qname`), you should include it in your project or install it as a gem